# How to extract the data from pandas dataframe between two dates?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

[Initial "ImportDate" datatype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEQEh.png) [Initial Pandas Dataframe interested in "ImportDate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcJ7h.png)

Problem statement -

I want to extract the data where "ImportDate" last till "1-1-2019". For eg - start_date to 1-1-2019. I tried converting "object" into "datetime64[ns] and wrote the code as

```
df[df['ImportDate'].between(4/26/2018, 1/1/2019)]
```

But resulted in an error while extracting the data:

```
"'>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float"
```

Can anyone help me how to deal with my problem statement?

Comment: `df[df['ImportDate'].between(start_date,end_date)]` , take a look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html)

Comment: I tried that but it showed an error - "<class 'int'> type object 1993" @anky_91

Comment: ok. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Comment: @anky_91 I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I have reframed my  question and also uploaded a photo of a dataframe I'm using. I hope it helps .

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your input in the `between` function are not dates. You should try to convert them :

```
df[df['ImportDate'].between(pd.to_datetime("4/26/2018"), pd.to_datetime("1/1/2019"))]
```

Or directly create date objects : `datetime.date(2019,1,1)` (do not forget to `import datetime`).

As stated, it would be easier to check if you can provide a piece of data.

Answer (score 0):

Is the column you say is a datetime really datetime? Fro mthe error you posted, it looks like it is not. Please check once more with df.dtypes. if its is not a datetime object, then convert it to datetime with for example `df['ImportDate']= pd.to_datetime(df['ImportDate'],format='%d/%m/%y')` (you will have to tweak parameters to suit your data). Then you can do `df[df['ImportDate'].between(start_date,end_date)]`

Comment: thank you. I tried your code but still shows the error. So now I/m starting my problem from the scratch. I have re framed my problem statement again. Can you please check it out and help me with it

Comment: according to the photo you uploaded, the type of "ImportDate" is "object". To convert it to datetime, you should use `df['ImportDate']= pd.to_datetime(df['ImportDate'],unit=s,format='%d/%m/%y')` (you will have to tweak parameters to suit your data).